# Python Iterating Array of URI to retrieve JSON

Tags: python, loops

I have a dynamically created array of URIs that I want to iterate through for retrieval of json data, which I'll then use to search a particular field for a specific value.  Unfortunately, I keep getting syntax errors.

```
for i in list_url_id:{
    var t = requests.get(base_url+i+'?limit='+str(count),auth=HTTPBasicAuth(uname,pw)).json()
    print(t)
}
```

If I do a `print(i)` in the loop, it prints the full URL out properly.  I'm lost.

EDIT: 
`base_url` is a URL similar to https://www.abcdef.com:1443
the URI in `list_url_id` is a URI similar to /v1/messages/list/0293842
I have no issue (as mentioned) concatenating them into a print operation, but when used for the string for `requests.get`, it returns a nondescript syntax error

Comment: what language is it?

Comment: Python (hence the title)

Comment: Show example of the list contents, and the error message.

Comment: try changing `var t = ` in to `t =` :)

Comment: @ChrisJohnson I added examples in the original post above.  Here's the error

`  File "listag.py", line 33
    var t = requests.get(base_url+i+'?limit='+str(count),auth=HTTPBasicAuth(uname,pw)).json()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @StanvanRooy I've tried with and without "var" - both getting the same error.  This is Python 3.x

Comment: @lauchlinmac then try to remove the brackets around the for loop.

Comment: @StanvanRooy but without the brackets, it will just return the last loop or am I missing something here.

Comment: @lauchlinmac python does not use brackets like that. It sees the code between it as a dictionary and obviously, that's not the right syntax for a dictionary.

Comment: Noted - indentation is how to delineate the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python sees the code inside the bracket as a dictionary, that's probably causing the syntax errors.

Indentation is used in Python for traversing `for` loops.

```
for i in list_url_id:
    t = requests.get(base_url+i+'?limit='+str(count),auth=HTTPBasicAuth(uname,pw)).json()
    print(t)
```

This should work for you and note that `var` is also removed as it is the wrong syntax. Python variables do not need an explicit declaration to reserve memory space. The declaration happens automatically when you assign a value to a variable.